# Is the assignment operator in JS a (re)binding or a mutation?

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, language-lawyer, assignment-operator

I'm trying to understand if the assignment operator in JavaScript should be intended as a (re)binding, as opposed to a mutation. In other words, given the following:

```
let x = 10;
x = 20;
```

I'd like to understand if the second line causes the bits encoding the value `10` to be modified so as to encode the value `20`, or – alternatively – if the `x` identifier gets rebound with some other (possibly new) chunk of memory, which was initialized so as to contain the value `20`.

The latter alternative is the common explanation I've found (e.g., in 
[ECMA-262-5 in detail](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/es5-chapter-3-1-lexical-environments-common-theory/#name-binding)). The upside of this explanation is that it allows presenting primitive type as immutable values, and confining mutation as an operation on the `object` type alone.

However, the idea binding to a different block of memory each time an assignment is performed looks odd, especially when considering how the same operation is performed in languages such as C and C++. Indeed, in C (and C++), an assignment causes a mutation in the bits associated with the identifier, while preserving the variable identity. That is:

```
int x = 10;
cout << &x << endl;
x = 20;
cout << &x << endl;
```

will print the same address. A rebinding would instead cause `x`'s location in memory to change.

Unfortunately, I could not find an explanation in the standard. Is there an authorative source I can rely upon? If – instead - this is vendor-dependent, which is the most common approach?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I rephrased those sentences referring to "new blocks of memory", as they were biasing the discussion. I'm mostly interested in understanding if the assignment operation is JS is an identity-preserving one.

Comment: Even if it is a rebind, there is no need for a new block of memory to be allocated as long as the correct semantics are preserved.

Comment: How could you tell the difference?

Comment: @melpomene: My question is more about how to describe the semantics of the assigment operator in JS in the most faithful way. Externally, the two approaches exhibit no difference,  given the fact that there is no way of inspecting the memory location of each variable.

Comment: @DarkFalcon: I took the part about binding to a new block from the mentioned reference, which is the most authorative source I could find. However, I'm mostly interested in undestanding if the assignment operation in JS is an identity-preserving operation.

Comment: I don't think its specified. So different JS engines could handle it different. Or even different depending on the context.

Comment: It's a mutation in the sense that closures will see the update: `let x = "foo"; let f = function () { return x; }; x = "bar"; console.log(f());` outputs `"bar"`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "*identity-preserving*". JS variables do not have any identity other than their name, especially they do not have an address.

Comment: @Bergi: Within JS, I agree with you that there is no way to tell. Nevertheless, I would like to know which of the two semantics is typically implemented under the hood. In other words, If you had to explain assignment in JS, would you opt for the mutation explanation or the rebinding explanation? Something like "when performing an assignment, the interpreter...."

Comment: @IlioCatallo: Mutation, definitely. Even what you call "rebinding" is just a mutation of the pointer stored in the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment is a mutation of the variable to hold a different value than before.

Whether that value is stored in a chunk of memory and only referenced by the contents of the variable, or encoded in the contents of the variable itself, doesn't really make a difference for immutable primitive values such as `10` and `20`.

Object values however are explicitly only references, as also shown in the article you linked.

> the idea of allocating a new block of memory each time an assignment is performed looks odd

That never happens indeed. Even if the assignment is just changing a reference, the referenced memory (containing the value) already exists prior to the assignment.